# Capybara - overriding an attribute on the node

Tags: ruby, capybara

Lets say I successfully retrieve some Capybara node:

```
node = find("#some-element")
```

The element has some nasty attribute that I just want to ignore or override for the context of the given test:

```
node[:onClick] # "someInlineJSCrap(); return false;"
```

Is it possible to override an attribute on the Capybara node?  I've tried ruby hash assignment syntax with no luck;

```
node[:onClick] = "return true;"
```

**Edit (full error):**

```
undefined method `[]=' for # <Capybara::Element tag="a"> (NoMethodError)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: could you tell me what's the full error stack ?

Comment: @Priti added the error.  It's a Capybara NoMehthodError on an anchor tag, nothing extraordinary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i don't know if that's even possible, but i think that i have a workaround for you.

you can use `page.execute_script` to change the `onClick` value of your node via JavaScript.

that would be something like `page.execute_script("$('#some-element').attr('onClick', 'return true;')")`